# Java-Spring - What to name a class that populates a jsp but with no controller methods

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller, naming

I have a controller class which is extended by several other controllers on my current project. The parent class has no actual controller methods on it, and is only used to populate a model-view based on certain user conditions. (It returns populated model back to whatever child-class method is calling it). Currently I'm refactoring it out so that this isn't a parent class to every controller in my project. Here is where my problem lies: What do you call a java class which has only the responsibility of populating a view? My coworkers argue quite fervently for calling it a "service", but do you guys have any other ideas?

Comment: suppose you mean you need to return a view ( JSP) via the controller. just put the  `modelAndView.setViewName("sample");`and return via the controller.

Comment: Could be ViewHelper? It's not exact ViewHelper pattern but looks similar

Comment: I think it should be Controller only. As it still have code to populate ModelandView.

Comment: What does everyone think about "provider" suffix for something like this? As it only provides the model to the corresponding controllers.